# What is the correct way to sync a database?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-connection

Assume I have one large database (mongoDB for example) that is used by many users and is installed on a server. I'm building a desktop application that should be able to interact with the database and should also be able to function temporarily if the internet connection is lost. 
My idea is that locally, I would have a clone of the DB on the server that I would change if no internet is available, and then when the internet is back, I would somehow sync both of these databases. However I can't help but think that this isn't the correct approach. How would this sync happen efficiently? Are there any alternatives or better approaches I could take?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongo-connector `https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector` to sync the database between two mongo instances. 
Another solution is to set up a replica between your local instance and remote instance. But you need to be aware that only primary can accept write operations which means when you go offline, your server instance can only handle write operations. Your local changes will be replicated to the server when you connect to the internet.